# APUE 10.3 signal: pointer cast issue.

Tags: c

i am learning the APUE 10.3 signal, and just confusing the define of `SIG_ERR`, `SIG_DFL` and `SIG_IGN`. here is the definition:

```
 #define SIG_ERR (void (*)())-1
 #define SIG_DFL (void (*)())0
 #define SIG_IGN (void (*)())1
```

and here is the signal function prototype:

```
 void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int)
```

When we call `signal(signo, SIG_DFL)`, why there is no function mismatch issue since the 2nd parameter should be `void (*)(int))`, however, what we provided `SIG_DFL` is the type of `(void (*)())`, `void (*)(int))` vs `(void (*)())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function declared like this : `type function()` means that you don't specify the parameters of that function, so you can call that function with any parameters or none. In fact, this just tells the compiler to ignore type-checking for the parameters of that function, since you don't use them.
The proper way to declare a function with no parameters is `type function(void)`.

So, in fact, when type checking `void (*)())` against `void (*)(int))`, the compiler only checks the return value type.

Note that it isn't true in C++, only in C. In C++, `type function()` is equivalent to `type function(void)`.

You can check out the official **C99** specification [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). Function definitions are at **6.9.1**, page 141.

Comment: thanks for all your guys' help. could you please let me know the evidence of it? i mean the books, documents or specs that i am able to learn it?

Answer (score 1):

While it would be okay in C (where a function without an explicit `void` argument takes an indeterminate number of indeterminate type arguments), those definitions will not work in C++.

However, while you may have found these in the book, they don't exist in that form on real systems, just because it has to work in C++ as well. For example, on my Linux system I have

```
#define SIG_DFL ((__sighandler_t) 0
```

where `__sighandler_t` is

```
typedef void (*__sighandler_t) (int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Blank  bracket `()` in function declaration means function can take unspecified argument. Please do not be confuse with `void` argument which describes no argument.